# Connectedness of automorphism group of a variety

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, connectedness

Let $Y$ be a proper, smooth, integral variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero. Consider the automorphism group $Aut_k(Y)$ (a group scheme).

> Are there any natural conditions on $Y$ such that $Aut_k(Y)$ is connected?